Is it safe to use a battery charger with an output voltage higher than the battery voltage?
I apologise in advance for any erroneous or obvious points or terms I may use.
I have a Remington beard grooming razor, which originally contained a 1.2V 700mAh NiMH rechargeable AAA battery, which became progressively weaker with use.  I replaced the battery with a 1.2v 1300mAh NiMH rechargeable AA battery and operated successfully.
The original Remington charger has an output of 3.6V --- 100mAh 0.36VA
I am a novice with electronics and batteries, but does even the original charger output appear safe?  It may appear that the higher output voltage of the charger is what may have contributed to the battery's rapid decline.  Would that be correct?
Unfortunately, the original charger is no longer functional.
I have acquired a similar Panasonic charger with an output of 4.6V 0.6A

Would it be safe to use the replacement charger to charge the battery?

If so, what impact will the higher voltage of the replacement charger have on the battery?

Should charge times be re-calculated?



For a single 1.2 V NiMH cell,I would expect a charger voltage of about 1.4 V.


The original Remington charger has an output of 3.6V --- 100mAh 0.36VA

Regarding the output of 3.6V: was that measured with no load connected?  Does that voltage drop significantly when the load is, say a 1kΩ resistor?

I am a novice with electronics and batteries, but does even the
original charger output appear safe?

If the charger output voltage drops down to, say, 1.5V (or lower) when attached to a load of about 5mA, then it's probably OK.  However, if the voltage stays above 1.5V when a load of, say, 100mA is attached, then this is likely not the correct charger for this battery, and will destroy the battery.

Unfortunately, the original charger is no longer functional. I have acquired a
similar Panasonic charger with an output of 4.6V 0.6A

Would it be safe to use the replacement charger to charge the battery?

If so, what impact will the higher voltage of the replacement charger
have on the battery?

Should charge times be re-calculated?



The test to apply to your charger is as follows:
Measure charger output voltage under these conditions:

No load connected.
A load of about 1mA.
A load of about 100mA.

If the results for Test 2 & Test 3 are both above 1.5V, then reject this charger - it is not suitable.  Using it will destroy your batteries, and could cause the battery case to rupture.
However, if the result of either or both Test 2 or Test 3 is 1.5V or lower, then this charger may be suitable, but more investigation is required.
My recommendation:
Obtain the charger specified by the battery manufacturer.  Getting this wrong could not only damage your battery, but could cause injury or fire.
Appendix
This is the charging curve for a typical NiMH battery cell:

Link for image above:
https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/nickelmetalhydride_appman.pdf

The original charger of 3.6V is in fact the original charger included with the razor when purchasing from new. I purchased two of these years apart and both came with the exact same charger. This was also confirmed by another consumer of the same model.

@jimjamz Although that may be ressuring, I would recommend making the measurements as per my answer.  Manufacturers may change items without notice; & just because they look the same on the outside that does not mean they are the same internally.
